# Provider has no access to class variables after being initialized in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-components, ng-bootstrap, angular-providers

I have created the following project https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-agzqbf You can see in the console the variable `x` is `undefined` from the beginning, even after initializing the variable in `ngOnInit`

[image]

The function that prints out the value of `x` is `format()` which is a function inherited from the parent class, and it is called every time a date is selected in the `input` field with calendar. But it is always `undefined` even after changing its value with a button calling `changeValue()`

Is this the normal behavior of providers? or how can I make sure the `format()` function has access to the variable class?

app.component.html

```
<form class="form-inline">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input class="form-control" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd"
             (focus)="d.open()" name="dp" [(ngModel)]="model" ngbDatepicker #d="ngbDatepicker">
      <div class="input-group-append">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary calendar" (click)="d.toggle()" type="button"></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>


<button (click)="changeValue()"> Change X value</button>
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NgbDateParserFormatter, NgbDateStruct } from "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: []
})
export class AppComponent extends NgbDateParserFormatter implements OnInit {
  title = 'test-project';

  x: number;
  model;

  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.x = 9;
  }

  changeValue() {
    this.x = 5;
    console.log('x changed', this.x);
  }

  private padNumber(value: number) {
    if (this.isNumber(value)) {
        return `0${value}`.slice(-2);
    } else {
        return "";
    }
  }

  private isNumber(value: any): boolean {
    return !isNaN(this.toInteger(value));
  }

  private toInteger(value: any): number {
    return parseInt(`${value}`, 10);
  }

  parse(value: string): NgbDateStruct {
    if (value) {
      const dateParts = value.trim().split('/');
      if (dateParts.length === 1 && this.isNumber(dateParts[0])) {
        return {year: this.toInteger(dateParts[0]), month: null, day: null};
      } else if (dateParts.length === 2 && this.isNumber(dateParts[0]) && this.isNumber(dateParts[1])) {
        return {year: this.toInteger(dateParts[1]), month: this.toInteger(dateParts[0]), day: null};
      } else if (dateParts.length === 3 && this.isNumber(dateParts[0]) && this.isNumber(dateParts[1]) && this.isNumber(dateParts[2])) {
        return {year: this.toInteger(dateParts[2]), month: this.toInteger(dateParts[1]), day: this.toInteger(dateParts[0])};
      }
    }   
    return null;
  }

  format(date: NgbDateStruct): string {
    console.log('x value', this.x);
    let stringDate: string = ""; 
    if(date) {
      stringDate += this.isNumber(date.year) ? date.year + "/" : "";
      stringDate += this.isNumber(date.month) ? this.padNumber(date.month) + "/" : "";
      stringDate += this.isNumber(date.day) ? this.padNumber(date.day) : "";
    } 
    return stringDate;
  }
}
```

PS: both `parse()` and `format()` functions are inherited from the parent class to set the correct format in the input field after selecting a date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lets look at NgModule description

```
providers: [{ provide: NgbDateParserFormatter, useClass: AppComponent}]
```

this string means that when something tries to inject `NgbDateParserFormatter` angular will create `AppComponent` and passes it instead. To achieve what you are trying to achieve add providers section to app component with `useExisting: AppComponent` like this:

```
@Component({
...
providers: [{ provide: NgbDateParserFormatter, useExisting: AppComponent }]
})
export class AppComponent{
...
```

Comment: awesome! Thanks Andrei, I was struggling with this so much! Can you elaborate more on why this works? Was an instance of AppComponent being created every time the provider was used?

Comment: no, `providers: [{ provide: NgbDateParserFormatter, useClass: AppComponent}] ` creates 1 AppComponent in some way like service. i.e. it has no template or element attached to. As a result you got 2 instances of AppComponent: 1 root component of your app and 2nd just instance of class that you provided in module. My changes made angular to `useExisting` app component as NgbDateParserFormatter rather than creating new one

Answer (score 1):

1.You need to add a service

I named it as data.service.ts, this service will update the value of your x whenever you use the xValueChange method.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject'

@Injectable()
export class DataService {

  private x = new BehaviorSubject<number>(3); 
  valueOfx = this.x.asObservable();
  constructor() { }

  xValueChange(newValue: number) {
    this.x.next(newValue);
  }
}
```

Stackblizt will ask you to install rxjs, when the option appears you shall accept it.

2. You have to add the service in the app.module.ts

here is the full code

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { NgbModule, NgbActiveModal, NgbDatepicker, NgbDateParserFormatter } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { DataService } from './services/data.service';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    NgbModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  providers: [{ provide: NgbDateParserFormatter, useClass: AppComponent}, DataService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

3. Finally you need to add the service to your constructor in the app.component.ts

here is a part of the code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NgbDateParserFormatter, NgbDateStruct } from "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap";
import { DataService } from './services/data.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: []
})
export class AppComponent extends NgbDateParserFormatter implements OnInit {
  title = 'test-project';

  x: number;
  model;

  constructor(private data :DataService) {
    super();
    this.data.valueOfx.subscribe(xValue => this.x = xValue);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.x = 9;
  }

  changeValue() {
    this.x = 5;
    this.data.xValueChange(5);
    console.log('x changed', this.x);
  }
```

After it, you shall see that the x value do not lose his changed value. Ill upload the stackblitz later today so you can see it working there.

Comment: this does not work, if you change the date in the input field, `9` will be printed out in the console

Comment: excuse me, let me search quickly for the answer. you will need to have a service instead, just give me a second to add the code

Comment: yeah, this works, but I was actually trying to avoid using a new service for this... and I thought the solution was more related to angular providers. Thanks though, if you can, please provide the stackblitz as well like you said ;)